# C pointers to pointers, characters

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, char

I've been trying to solve this for hours. Including research, but no go. Basically, we have to create function with :

`int reverseSentence(char** sentence, char ** newsentance, int maxWords){`

Where it returns the number of words in a sentence.

Here's more information:

You must maintain sentence capitalization, meaning if the sentence was capitalized, keep the
capital. If a word was capitalized, such as a name, retain the capital

- The parameter sentence is a reference to a character array with the sentence to
  reverse and should not be directly modified by your function. Each word is an array
  entry in sentence.
- The parameter newsentance is a reference to a character array to hold the new
  sentence.
- The parameter maxWords is the maximum size of the character array.
- Return the number of words in the sentence
- Do not copy the strings to temporary storage and replace them in the sentence. Move
  the pointers.

ex: “To be, or not to be: that is the question.” becomes ”Question the is that be: to not or be, to.

Now, the problem I have is, currently my code works. But I can't seem to think of a way to capitalize something without getting an error. (Since we can't make a new storage).

What I have here is basically part of my code:

```
char ** fptr = sentence; //front sentence
char ** lptr = sentence; //last sentence
char ** nptr = newsentance;//front of new sentance

 if( isupper(**fptr)){ //if the first letter of the first word is capital set flag
   capflag = 1;
}
// find last word before null sentence and also calculate size

while(**(++lptr)) 
   ++size;      

 --lptr;

 if(capflag){ 
    *nptr = *lptr;
    **nptr = toupper(**lptr);            //error here
 }
```

Also, I had to assume that the last "word" in sentence is "" or I can't find a way to calculate the size of the sentence. I hope someone can help me out.

I used this to test:

```
  char ** test = malloc(1000);
   *test = "To ";
   *(test+1) = "be ";
   *(test+2) = "or ";
   *(test+3) = "not ";
   *(test+4) = "to ";
   *(test+5) = "be ";
   *(test+6) = "";
   char ** ztest = malloc(1000);
   int rs = reverseSentence(test, ztest, 1000 );
```

Comment: Could you specify the exact input you want to feed to this function?

Comment: Seems to me this should work - as maxim suggests perhaps post the code where you set up the sentence buffers and call the function.

Comment: i added code that i used to test: @MaximSkurydin

Comment: Are you sure that the reversed sentence capitalization is correct?  You seem to have capitalized 'Question' and uncapitalized 'To' when you were told to leave the words alone?  The instructions do not state how you detect the end of sentence in the `sentence` parameter.  It's a moderately reasonable guess that a null pointer marks the end of the sentence, but it is a guess.  It also appears that you don't have to allocate the memory; it is already allocated for you.

Comment: The problem is this code fails at runtime. If I remove the if(capflag) it would be be to not or be To

Comment: @Vyktor well I'm using Dev-C++, but when I press run it would say program stopped responding.. I'm thinking segmentation fault.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I can't think of a way to assign the newsentence a modified word. Like, from question to Question, without manipulating the original itself.

Comment: Since you're told to just move the pointers, I don't think you should be changing the data that the pointers point at all.  Of course, I may be misreading the rules according to your assignment, but that would be my interpretation.  And my answer runs according to my interpretation (which may or may not help you).  If you must capitalize words, then you need to make copies of string literals before modifying them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code tries to modify a string literal, which is undefined behavior (you cannot do "ABC"[1] = 48; some implementations put string literals to readonly memory). 
Try allocating space using malloc for each individual string and copy data from each string literal using memcpy.

Comment: How can this be done? I know I had this problem before for char * 's all I did was use char [] instead. How to do this for 2D?

Comment: I started to initalize with char[] and pointed to them. It works great. Thank you!

Comment: for example, const char *src = "ABC"; size_t string_length = strlen( src ) + 1; *( test+4 ) = malloc( string_length ); memcpy( *( test +4 ), "abcd", string_length ); or you can use the approach you described. char line1[] = "ABC"; declares an array with 4 characters initializes it with contents of a string literal and you can modify it.

Comment: @Kalon This answer does not answer your question, and if you simply test with string arrays instead of literals so as to be able to modify the strings, you will almost certainly fail the automated tester.

Answer (score 0):

The code below gives me the output:

```
To be or not to be; that is the question.
Number of words: 10
To be or not to be; that is the question.
question. the is that be; to not or be To
```

It only shuffles (copies of) pointers around; it does not attempt to modify the capitalization of words.  If was going to do that, it would have to work harder, allocating copies of the leading word in the original sentence (but how would you tell whether that was a name or not?) and the last word.  Suppose the sentence was "London hosted the 2012 Olympics"; when reversed, you don't want to case-convert the L of London because it is a name that happens to start the sentence (and you don't need to case-convert the O of Olympics either).

You could legitimately decide that the full stop (period) at the end of the sentence should not be included in the data (so my `"question."` should be replaced by `"question"`), and then have the sentence printing code add the full stop at the end; it is a trivial modification.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int reverse_sentence(char **fwd_order, char **rev_order, int max_words)
{
     char **end = fwd_order;
     int    num_words = 0;
     for (end = fwd_order; *end != 0 && num_words < max_words; end++)
         num_words++;
     for (int i = 0; i < num_words; i++)
         *rev_order++ = *--end;
     *rev_order = 0;
     return num_words;
}

static void print_sentence(char **words)
{
     const char *pad = "";
     while (*words)
     {
         printf("%s%s", pad, *words++);
         pad = " ";
     }
     putchar('\n');
}

int main(void)
{
     char *sentence[] =
     { "To", "be", "or", "not", "to", "be;", "that", "is", "the", "question.", 0 };
     enum { NUM_WORDS = sizeof(sentence) / sizeof(sentence[0]) };
     char *reversed[NUM_WORDS];
     int num_words;

     print_sentence(sentence);
     num_words = reverse_sentence(sentence, reversed, NUM_WORDS);
     printf("Number of words: %d\n", num_words);
     print_sentence(sentence);
     print_sentence(reversed);
     return(0);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

*ex: “To be, or not to be: that is the question.” becomes ”Question the is that be: to not or be, to.*

Is this part of the specification or is it your interpretation? If the latter, you should verify whether your interpretation is correct or whether you are to simply reverse the order of the words, which is easily achievable. Do you even know if you are required to handle punctuation? Your code doesn't, and your test doesn't match your example.

First rule of software engineering: nail down the requirements.

Comment: The example is part of the specification. I cannot achieve this, but so far I can achieve reversing order only. For example: "Hi there 123" becomes "123 there Hi"

Comment: So the specification includes the period at the end of the sentence and requires it to stay there? Why doesn't your test look like that specification?